# What would cause a room to disappear in the game Screeps?

Tags: screeps

I spawned in room E62N94 on Shard 0 a few hours prior to posting this question. When I logged back in later the same day to check on my creeps, I found my room and most of the rest of the sector awash in RED.  Also, it looks like there is a string of portals running down the West side of the sector.

All of the structures that I built have disappeared, and I no longer have any claim to the room controller.  I have been completed wiped out a few times, and it has never happened like this before.

Do you have any idea what could have happened to my room? It should have been in safe mode for the rest of the day, and some of tomorrow.

There is no history available in the room for me to review.